# How to selectively disable use of keep-alive on a single HttpURLConnection in Java?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, keep-alive

I'm facing a scenario where we are using a library which uses HttpURLConnection to perform multiple requests to the same host.
For some of these requests (non all!) I need to disable keep-alive, so that after sending the request the connection is not reused.
My first bet was to configure so that the following header is sent:

```
Connection: close
```

however this header does -not- change the behaviour of the HttpURLConnection. On the contrary this is causing problems because:

- the server reads the header and thinks that the client will close the connection
- the client (HttpURLConnection) does not interpret it and thus re-uses the connection (contrary to what it declared to the server!)

According to official documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html
there is a system property "http.keepAlive" which is however global and does not fit my requirements.
Also according to the above we could simply not read the response body, thus causing the connection to be scrapped, however we need to read the response and also this way is not feasible.

Any header/property/whatever we can use to force JVM HttpURLConnection to close the connection after using it for a single request-response?